# Qt C++ Как открыть файл по нажатой кнопке

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, doc

Привет Всем. Есть кнопка pushButton и есть файл, не важно html pdf doc(Вордовский). Как по нажатию по кнопке открыть данный файл, так же ,как мы по нему кликаем мышью 2 раза и он запускается Microsoft Office Word если это док, Pdf Viewer если это pdf, html если это браузер, только нужно по кнопке из программы Gui. Путь к файлу например лежит С:\book. И можно ли такие файлы данных форматов пихать в ресурс файлы проекта? что бы грузить из него?

Comment: нет мне не нужен OpenFileDialog и его окно, путь к файлу статичен. Как щас наткнулся можно юзать QProcess.

Comment: Понял, тогда exec, shellexecute, winexec или на крайний случай openprocess

Comment: из ресурсов теоретически можно но совсем не все. Не все приложения корректно работают с res: протоколом. В некоторые COM ActiveX можно динамически подгружать документ но это другой вид открытия (сь ф-ции OleRun, CoCreateInstance IOleSite).

Comment: спасибо, почитаю про это для общего развития, а если я хочу что бы приложение было кроссплатформенным? то тут все кроме exec под винду, как понял.

Comment: Щас веду разработку под виндой, но приложение должно работать и на Linux.

Comment: Да и ты написал, только заметил.  Что res: является протоколом ???? причем тут протокол? файлы .rc эти файлы в ехе зашиваются.

Comment: Вот пример (для IE) `res://msxml3.dll/XML/DEFAULTSS.XSL` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Довольно несложно поддерживать протокол, файл по любому из протоколов открывается в строк 10 ( wininet.h). Поставив у себя Internet.Application на странице можно открыть картинки с ресурсов и разместить гипертекст с ссылками, страницу htm тоже зашить в ресурсы))). Но это не кроссплатформенно.

Comment: Ресурсы, ещё есть в Win DDE "протокол" (Dynamic Data Exchange),   - это открытие DDE-совместимого приложения и передача в него данных. DDE поддерживает весь офис, и некоторые программы крупных фирм.

Answer (score 1):

Для открытия файлов как будто на них дважды кликнули в проводнике используйте метод [QDesktopServices::openUrl](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl). Для получения `QUrl`, указывающего на локальный файл используйте метод [QUrl::fromLocalFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurl.html#fromLocalFile).

Для открытия файла из ресурсов, делаете также как архиваторы открывают файлы – копируете файл из ресурсов в временную папку и открываете его.